# How to delete all records of a table above a certain number for clean up purpose

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

To illustrate my question, let's take the example of rolling log files. You set a cap in bytes and every bytes that go over it, is deleted to let place to the new entries.

I need something similar for my database and I want to create a query that will be executed daily.

The query will delete all old records in the **table T** above a **number N** of records.

Records will be sorted by date descending of course.

There are multi millions records in that table.

Comment: Which database you are using?

Comment: Sorry for that, I added the three most popular database our customers use.

Answer (score 3):

If `ID` is the primary key of T:

```
delete T where ID not in (select top N ID from T order by date_column desc)
```

Comment: Don't you think querying for millions ID will cause performance issues?

Comment: If there is an index on T.date_column and N is not very large then this should be quite fast.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work.

```
DELETE FROM <table> WHERE date < (
 SELECT min(date) FROM (
   SELECT date FROM table
   ORDER BY date DESC
   LIMIT N
 )
)
```

Inner select finds the top N newer records.
Then the middle select finds the older date of those one and the outer select deletes everything older than that.

Comment: You might be leaving more than `N` records in the origin table when doing so, if there are several entires with the same timestamp. However this appears to be a fairly good approximation, and for the OP purpose should do the job actually.

Answer (score 2):

You don't specify RDBMS. For SQL Server

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Dt DESC) AS Rn
FROM T
)
DELETE FROM CTE
WHERE Rn > 100000
```

Answer (score 1):

If I have right understand your question, you need something like

```
DELETE FROM T WHERE ID IN (SELECT TOP 1000 ID FROM T AS T1 WHERE T1.DATE > @DATE )
```

In this example N = 1000, and the minimum date is @DATE

Comment: this would delete the rows the OP intend to keep

Answer (score 1):

For ORACLE

```
delete from T 
where rowid not in ( select rowid 
                     from (select rowid from T order by date desc)
                     where rownum <= N
                    )
```

Comment: I'd be inclined to use NOT EXISTS over NOT IN

Answer (score 1):

For Oracle (enterprise), you might consider range [partitioning](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/options/partitioning/index.html) a big table by date.  You can then drop or truncate the partition(s) you wish very easily (and quickly).  Definitely not a generic solution though.